# CSS Grid/Flexbox for dynamic content in Django

Tags: css, django, flexbox, django-templates, grid

I am using Django for a project, and I have a wireframe CSS grid layout, 4 across at the moment, and I want to know how I can replace these wireframe components with dynamic content using Django.

I know that `{% for post in posts %}` would work for me in a straight down list way, but how can I make this work in a grid system, so it'll break to a new line whenever it reaches 4 across in the grid. I am stumped and haven't found anything online on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For data insertion, you still need to use `{% for post in posts %}` for the breaking down will take care your `css` at rendering time in the browser.
Because is no difference between list view or grid view from point of data autputing, it's just a different way of its visualization

```
<div class="your-grid">
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="grid-element">
        {{ post }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<style>
.your-grid
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr, 4);
  grid-gap: 8px;
}
<style>
```